# Copy data from Hive Table to Local system with column headers and pipe delimited with compression

Tags: hive

Im using the following command to copy all the data from hive table to local file system

```
bin> hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from sample' > /home/mydir/sample_file.txt
```

I am able to copy the data successfully but  the headers are in the form tablename.columnname and i just want to have only the column_name and has the delimiter the same as the table.

I am looking for parameters that will enable me to create the file along with the headers(column_name only) and fields delimited as pipe (|) with compression if possible.

I tried adding

```
sed 's/[\t]/,/g'
```

to the command but its not giving me the required result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;`.  That should result in hive not giving you tablename.columnname.

Comment: Is it possible to compress the file while it is being created. My files are around 400 GB.

Comment: Compressing the output of a query as part of the execution depends on lots of factors.  Give [this wiki entry](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LZO) a read.